# Extracting utterance per line in python

Tags: python, nltk, text-processing

I have text data containing one utterance per line. I want to extract it so I have a list containing the all utterance with the same length of the line.

Here is an example of my data `input.txt`

```
I am very happy today.
Are you angry with me...? No?
Oh my dear, you look so beautiful.
Let's take a rest, I am so tired. 
Excuse me. This is my fault.
```

Currently, I use the following python code:

```
from nltk import tokenize

utterances = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        utterance = tokenize.sent_tokenize(line)
        utterances = np.append(utterances, utterance)
utterances = list(utterances)
len(utterances)
```

It gives the total of utterance: 7, it should be 5 same with input data.

I am expecting the following output (list of 5 utterances),

```
['I am very happy today.', 'Are you angry to me...? No?', 'Oh my dear, you looks so beautiful.', "Let's take a rest, I am so tired.", 'Excuse me. This is my fault.']
```

While the present python code above resulting the following output (7 sentences).

```
['I am very happy today.', 'Are you angry to me...?', 'No?', 'Oh my dear, you look so beautiful.', "Let's take a rest, I am so tired.", 'Excuse me.', 'This is my fault.']
```

Is there anything better than `tokenize.sent_tokenize` from NLTK? I think this the reason I got the wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply appending to the list without `np.append()` and 'sent_tokenize' works

```
from nltk import tokenize

utterances = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as myfile:
for line in myfile.readlines():
    utterance = line.strip('\n')
    utterances.append(utterance)
print(utterances)
```

Comment: Almost perfect. But still, there is bracket for every utterance. I will mark it as answer if you could update it.

Comment: @bagustris edited to obtain a flattened list rather than list of lists

Comment: Now I got `len(utterance_list)` is 7 not 5 as I expected.

Comment: Edited now, but then you don't need to tokenize sentences

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
utterance = tokenize.sent_tokenize(line)
```

you are asking `nltk` to tokenize your data into *sentences*, not *utterances*. This function considers `?` and `.` to mark the ends of sentences. Two of your lines of data have more than one sentence terminator in them, so the tokenizer considers them to be two sentences each. That is why your result contains 7 sentences (not 8 as you report): line 2 and line 5 are each split into two sentences.

Comment: Yes, you correct, I made typo to write 7 instead of 8. This is the problem I would like to solve. Is there any method to extract utterances instead of sentences?

Comment: According to your problem statement you already have one utterance per line. So calling `sent_tokenize()` changes your data from something you have and want, to something you don't want. Just leave out that line entirely. Then you won't need to flatten the list, either.